# Asking about if the class name should be include in the EXTRA TAG for Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am reading a book called Big nerd ranch for learning android .. and the author used an extra tag for the intent like this

```
public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_is_true";
```

geoquiz is a package and it included three classes:
1. QuizActivity
2. CheatActivity
3 TrueFalse

and the Extra tag inside the QuizActivity class ..

my question is .. 
should'd be written like this

```
    public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity.answer_is_true";
```

was the author mistaken or that was a normal things to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write any string into `EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE`. It's just a unique key identification name. The key value that you want to share between Two `Activities`.

### Example:

Suppose if you want to pass some info from one `Activity` to second `Activity` then

```
  Activity1:
  public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "Activity1";
  Intent i = new Intent(yourActivity.this,Activity2.class);
  i.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE , "message");


  Activity2:
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  String str = extras.getString(Activity1.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE);
```

Comment: So you mean .. It doesn't matter what is inside the String, the only thing that matter is it should be a unique ?

Comment: @WaseemSwaileh Yup. Absolutely